# Post value of button in node.js

Tags: node.js, post

I have a form that submits a query, which will eventually be executed in MySQL

however, I have an issue posting the text value of a button. I have a button wit a dropdown that allows the mode of query, and I need to be able to access this in my node.js post method. when trying to access the text or value of the button with id "searchmethod" it crashes saying that the button is undefined, however, my textbox returns post just fine.

EDIT:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at Object.handle (/root/Folder/app/routes.js:15:50) at next_layer (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13) at Route.dispatch (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5) at c (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24) at Function.proto.process_params (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12) at next (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19) at next_layer (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14) at next_layer (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14) at next_layer (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14) at Route.dispatch (/root/Folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)

HTML for the button/Form

```
<form method="post" action="/" class="box">
            <h3 style="color:#5F5F5F">Inventory Item Lookup</h3>
            <div class="input-group dropdown">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button name="searchmethod" id="search-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Name</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="drop-list-item"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                        <li class="drop-list-item"><a href="#">Manufacturer</a></li>
                        <li class="drop-list-item"><a href="#">Description</a></li>
                        <li class="drop-list-item"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="drop-list-item"><a href="#">Smart Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="searchstring" class="form-control" style="z-index: auto">
            </div>
        </form>
```

js code for post

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Search Function: ' + req.body.searchmethod.value + ":" + req.body.searchstring); // this will eventually cause a return from SQL
    console.log("Search Function: " + req.body.searchmethod.value + ":" +  req.body.searchstring);
});
```

req.body.searchstring works fine. req.body.searchmethod.value fails because "searchmethod" is undefined. searchmethod.text also fails.

Comment: You should post the relevant code and the exact error

Comment: Seriously, do you expect us to be able to figure out what your HTML and your code is from one paragraph of text?  Come on now.  If the question is about code and HTML, post the code and HTML or the question will need to be closed with insufficient information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments.. a bit difficult to understand what is actually going on here, a codepen or some working example would help people to answer your question.

One fundamental mistake looks evident here - Node doesn't understand HTML attributes - `req.body` will only contain `searchmethod` if a form element with a `name` property of `searchmethod` is included in the form. Then `.value` will not be necessary, `req.body.searchmethod` will contain the value.

E.g.

```
<form method="post" action="/" class="box">
    <input id="searchmethod" name="searchmethod" type="hidden" />
    <button id="searchbutton" ... >Name</button>
</form>
```

But you will need some JS to set the hidden value from the button click event..

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#searchbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('#searchmethod').val( $(this).text() );
});
```